# How do sort array with key, value in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have `ng-options`:

```
ng-options="k as v for (k, v) in countries"
```

where `v` is string name of element from array `country`. How I can sort this by `v`?

I tried standart `orderBy:v`, but does not work

Comment: `orderBy` only works on array - and `countries` is an object - which is unordered.

Comment: 1. Is countries an object or an array? If array, perhaps you forgot to enclose the v in quotes: orderBy:'v'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **orderBy** to sort your list ,,
docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

in your controller :

```
$scope.countries = Object.keys($scope.countries).map(function(item){
   return {
      k : item,
      v : $scope.countries[item]
   }
});
```

and use it like this :

```
ng-options="country.k as country.v for country in countries | orderBy:'v'"
```

Comment: could you please show me your code ??
I've used this code several times

Comment: I forgot to add `v`  in Orderby. Works, Thanks

Comment: you are welcome dude ,, glad that I could help you :)